# MorphAnnotator.addLemma produces a NullPointerException for a particular text stream

Tags: clojure, stanford-nlp

```
(def ^:private props
  (doto (java.util.Properties.)
    (.put "annotators" "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse")
    (.put "parse.maxlen" (str (-> config :nlp :max-sentence-length)))
    (.put "pos.maxlen" (str (-> config :nlp :max-sentence-length)))))

(def ^:private pipeline (StanfordCoreNLP. props))

(defn- annotated-doc [s]
   (.process pipeline s))

(def input-text (slurp "/home/you/some.txt"))

(annotated-doc input-text)
```

Which then produces either a properly annotated result as expected or it produces this exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>             MorphaAnnotator.java:68 edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.MorphaAnnotator.addLemma
>             MorphaAnnotator.java:55 edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.MorphaAnnotator.annotate
>          AnnotationPipeline.java:67 edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotationPipeline.annotate
>            StanfordCoreNLP.java:881 edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.annotate
>            StanfordCoreNLP.java:910 edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.process
>                    (Unknown Source) sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke
>   DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
>                     Method.java:606 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
>                   Reflector.java:93 clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod
>                   Reflector.java:28 clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod

The text file is very vanilla. I have reduced my annotators list down to what produces the issue. I have 6 GB of memory configured for it. The text file is 3886 characters long, UTF-8 BOM formatted file. It works with partial text from this file just fine. It even works if I take the whole file as in (take 3886 input-text). So I'm stumped. Not sure what to make of it. Any suggestions?

Here is a link to the text file I was using: http://nectarineimp.com/spooky-action.txt

From my project.clj file:

```
 :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp "3.3.1"]
                 [edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp "3.3.1" :classifier "models"]]
```

Comment: I found the sentence that is causing the null pointer exception. It doesn't help me understand this at all. However it says the problem isn't my code but a bug with the addLemma method.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is was a bug in the Annotator. I'm not sure what your configuration settings were for:

```
(def ^:private props
  (doto (java.util.Properties.)
    (.put "annotators" "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse")
    (.put "parse.maxlen" (str (-> config :nlp :max-sentence-length)))
    (.put "pos.maxlen" (str (-> config :nlp :max-sentence-length)))))
```

But they were irrelevant in reproducing the issue. I recently upgraded a project to version `3.5.2` and your code block ran without issues ([CoreNLP Version History](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#history)).

Running in `3.1.1` produces your results exactly. It looks like at version `3.5.0` a Java 1.8 JVM is required.

This bug appears to be fixed in version `3.4` of CoreNLP as well, which doesn't require JVM updates.

Your question was posted a while ago, so I'm pretty sure you've already figured all this out, but for the sake of Google, I've left these comments.

Comment: Yes it was fixed! I had a conversation with the good folks at Stanford and they came up with a fix. It requires the programmer to be more careful though. They aren't raising the exception, but they aren't processing the text anymore either. My original suggestion had been that a more useful exception be raised. It was good meeting you in person a few weeks ago. We should do that again.